# JavaScript: Capturing Enter key WITHOUT JS Framework

Tags: javascript

How can I detect when the "Enter" key is pressed in the window, and conditionally suppress it? I've found lots of solutions with jQuery and MooTools, but not a frameworkless version. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

you do that by adding a function to the onkeypress event of your documents body.

```
document.onkeypress = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
       alert('Enter key pressed');
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

To suppress any further action you'll have to return false at the end of the function.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: I think you meant event.keycode `===` 13 (or `==` at the very least)

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't think it will work in any browser. First, `keyCode` will be 0 for printable character keypresses in Firefox, for example. Second, as Russ Cam pointed out, you're missing an equals sign. Third, you have mis-typed "keyCode": note the capital "C" in the middle.

Comment: ... and fourth, `document.body.onkeypress` doesn't work in Firefox or IE: it needs to be `document.onkeypress`.

Comment: In the specific case of the enter key I will grant you that you do get 13 for `keyCode` in Firefox, so my first point was invalid, though the general principle remains true.

Answer (score 2):

This will work in all current mainstream browsers:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    if (charCode == 13) {
        alert("Enter");
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```